# How to create collada objects in pycollada

Tags: collada

Goal: I want to create a collada object/file with 5-10 cuboids in a 3-D space.

However, I am finding it very hard to follow the  documentation [here](http://pycollada.github.io/creating.html) to create the above object. In particular, I am unable to understand the following:

```
>>> vert_floats = [-50,50,50,50,50,50,-50,-50,50,50,
         -50,50,-50,50,-50,50,50,-50,-50,-50,-50,50,-50,-50]
>>> normal_floats = [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,
        0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,-1,0,0,
        -1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,-1,
        0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1]
```

1. What are `normal_floats` and `vert_floats` variables? What do the elements in these array represent? Why do we have 24 and 72 elements respectively?

```
>>> indices = numpy.array([0,0,2,1,3,2,0,0,3,2,1,3,0,4,1,5,5,6,0,
...     4,5,6,4,7,6,8,7,9,3,10,6,8,3,10,2,11,0,12,
...     4,13,6,14,0,12,6,14,2,15,3,16,7,17,5,18,3,
...     16,5,18,1,19,5,20,7,21,6,22,5,20,6,22,4,23])
```

2. What is the `indices` variable? Here too, what do these elements mean? These array also has 72 elements

The above code is produces the following cube

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The `vert_floats` are the vertex source data. The `normal_floats` are the normal source data. The `indices` index into the arrays. I'd suggest taking some time to familiarize yourself with the Collada spec. This page has a nice overview:

http://www.wazim.com/Collada_Tutorial_1.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you explain how the values chosen in `vert_floats`, `normal_float` and `indices` produce the above cube? In other words, how to come up with those values if one needs to produce a cube?

Comment: Sorry some of my answer got lost. Updated.